# HTML:Use quotes within quotes within quotes

Tags: javascript, html, string, quotes, double-quotes

I'm stuck with this problem:

```
<body onload="document.body.innerHTML="<script>alert('hi')</script>"">
```

The problem is that i cant use quotes within quotes within quotes.
Any ideas?

Comment: Does'nt simple escaping work in the string?

Comment: @Keshi — Define "simple escaping".

Comment: What problem do you intend to solve by doing that?

Comment: Even if you solve the quoting problem, the code won't do anything. Browsers don't evaluate script contents when you set `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To represent a `"` character inside an HTML attribute delimited by `"` characters, use the entity `&quot;`

I'd recommend [attaching event listeners using JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) rather then using intrinsic event attributes though. It simplifies things greatly.

Note however, that [browsers will not execute JavaScript added to the document with `innerHTML`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml). If you want to add a script programatically, the use `createElement` / `appendChild` et al.

Answer (score 10):

```
<body onload='document.body.innerHTML="<script>alert(\"hi\")</script>"'>
```

or

```
<body onload="document.body.innerHTML='<script>alert(\'hi\')</script>'">
```

It does work, but the script doesn't get executed because it is added after the browser parsed your code.

Note that if you wanted quotes within quotes within quotes within quotes you would have done: `<body onload="document.body.innerHTML='<script>alert(\'\\\'hi\\\'\')</script>'" >`

What is really impossible (i think) without `&quot;` is putting `"` and `'` in the alert.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of backticks(`), single quotes, and double quotes.

Code:

```js
<body onload="document.body.innerHTML=`<script>alert('hi')</script>`">
```

Answer (score 0):

Gah!  First off, don't do it that way.   :D

Something like:

```
<body></body>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.body.innerHTML = "<script>alert('hi')</script>";
    }
</script>
```

. . . would be better.  Consider some JQuery solutions, as well.

Even that specific approach, I wouldn't recommend, but I suspect that you are simply testing out how to add content to the body of your HTML after the page is loaded, rather than actually wanting to use the `alert()`.   ;)  If that's the case, try something like this:

```
<body></body>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.body.innerHTML = "some text";
        alert('hi'); // if you really want to test that the JS is working after load.
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this doesnt address the problem of "using quotes within quotes within quotes" at all

Comment: @InsOp - Sometimes question titles only capture part of a problem or one way of looking at a problem.  The code provided in the original question was not simply an issue of "using quotes within quotes within quotes" . . . the OP was trying to achieve a specific functionality and the multiple levels of quotes were causing him a problem in his approach.  One of the several ways to resolve his issue was to remove the logic that was causing a need for all those layers of quotes (the approach that I documented).  It may not have answered the question in the title, but it *does* solves his issue.

Comment: one can clearly see that this is an simplified example so we can address exactly the issue of "using quotes within quotes within quotes"

Comment: @InsOp - Just doing what the site guidelines suggest: "Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."  Others tried to help the OP use the quotes correctly, I tried to help him not have to use them at all.